# How can we show Azure AD security questions?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have used Azure AD B2C sign-in and sign-up policy for user login and signup process with Multi factor Authentication. Also set password resetting policy.

Everything is working fine with Phone factor (MFA).

Now client wants to add security questions while signing up a user and password resetting.

I have enabled security question and selected 5 questions; however, it's not visible while signing up a user and password resetting.

I am not able to understand what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the official documentation, Azure AD B2C only supports using a **verified email address** as a recovery method.

> Currently, we only support using a verified email address as a
>   recovery method. We will add additional recovery methods (verified
>   phone number, **security questions**, etc.) in the future.

In addition, Azure AD B2C only supports **phone call** and **text message** verification for Multi-Factor Authentication(MFA).

> Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C integrates directly with Azure
>   Multi-Factor Authentication so that you can add a second layer of
>   security to sign-up and sign-in experiences in your consumer-facing
>   applications. And you can do this without writing a single line of
>   code. Currently we support **phone call** and **text message** verification.

More information about MFA and password reset for Azure AD B2C, please refer to the following links.

- [Azure Active Directory B2C: Set up self-service password reset for
  your consumers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr)
- [Azure Active Directory B2C: Enable Multi-Factor
  Authentication in your consumer-facing applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa)

Comment: [uservoice.com - Security Questions For Password Recovery](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20291029-security-questions-for-password-recovery) @HemlataTripathi