# Does Azure Active Directory B2C already support Multifactor Authentication Security Questions?

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

Does anyone know if Azure Active Directory B2C already support Multifactor Authentication Security Questions?  And how to configure it?

I have stumbled into this old answer that was way back in 2017, and I am wondering if there are already updates from Microsoft.  I cannot find any yet.  The corresponding Microsoft Documentation was dated 2016.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41737326/943746

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure MFA can support 4 [verification options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-whats-next#selectable-verification-methods) to user:

> Call to phone
>
> Text message to phone
>
> Notification through mobile app
>
> Verification code from mobile app

[image]

So, Security Questions method is still not supported for AAD MFA. You can post this idea in [this Uservoice Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160602-multi-factor-authentication?category_id=160602), AAD team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the notification and code via the mobile app are not supported out of the box via built-in policies.  Perhaps with custom policies, you can make those work.